# Infinite loop while trying simple indentedBlock expression in pyparsing

Tags: pyparsing

I'm trying to parse indented blocks with pyparsing and `indentedBlock`

Here my code

```
from pyparsing import *

indent_stack = [1]
line = ungroup(restOfLine)
block = ungroup(indentedBlock(line, indent_stack))

# Work
data = """  foo
  bar
  tar
"""

block.parseString(data).pprint()
```

The problem is that `parseString` won't return. It seems to be waiting for more input or maybe I hit an infinite loop. If I put an unidnented line in the block start to work

```
data = """  foo
  bar
  tar

end
"""
```

But I want to be able to parse up to unindented line (the working case), or to the end of string (the not working case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in pyparsing. `indentedBlock` uses `OneOrMore` internally to implement the repetition of the embedded lines. But `restOfLine` does not fail if it is at the end of a line, and so once you get to the end of the string, `indentedBlock`'s repetition just keeps finding empty `restOfLine`s, and so `indentedBlock` just loops forever.

A workaround for now, until this bug gets fixed and released, is to change your definition of `line` from:

```
line = ungroup(restOfLine)
```

to

```
line = ungroup(~StringEnd() + restOfLine)
```

Comment: How you would read `~StringEnd() + restOfLine`? _line not followed by string end?_

Comment: Pyparsing works left-to-right through these expressions, so the check for end-of-string is done first. Read it as: _if I am not at the string end, read the rest of the current line_

Comment: There is one additional issue for doing further work with `indentedBlock`. In support of using `scanString`, and change was made internally to `indentedBlock` to add a fail action, but this change has adverse effects for other usages. For now, whenever you use `indentedBlock`, clear the fail action using `indentedBlock(... whatever args ...).setFailAction(None)`. When I was testing out your code and wanted to make it more general purpose, I needed to disable the fail action.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out exactly why the code is doing this. I even tried running it in Debug mode and pausing, but it wouldn't even pause so that I could see where it was getting stuck.

A workaround you could use for now is modifying the data to add an unindented line:

```py
from pyparsing import *

indent_stack = [1]
line = ungroup(restOfLine)
block = ungroup(indentedBlock(line, indent_stack))

# Work
data = """  foo
  bar
  tar
"""

block.parseString(data + "\nend").pprint()

# Result: [['foo'], ['bar'], ['tar']]
```